# jQuery .not() filter won't work

Tags: jquery, traversal

I've tried quite a few ways to filter out a class from a selection, including filter() and find() but can't get this to work.

I'm trying to create a 'lights out' feature for the currently viewed video. It's a simple piece of code, I must be doing something fundamentally wrong...

You can see the code in place at www.jaygeorge.co.uk/gwennan-sage/showreel.

What should happen: when you hover over the'lights out' bar, everything should disappear EXCEPT the closest video which has a 'playing' class on it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".lightsout").hover(function() {
    $(this).next().addClass('playing');     
    $('body').not(".playing").animate({opacity: 0, backgroundColor: 'black'}, 1000);
});
```

});

Comment: I think you should use an overlay div rather than doing this.

Comment: `$('body').not(".playing")` definitely does not work. `$('body')` will *only* select the `body` element, not any other element. `not()` filters the current selection. So it removes the `body` element from the selection if it has not the class `playing`.

Comment: Hmmm my friend suggested using a div overlay message, but that means setting z-indexes, I thought there would be a simpler method, just by hiding everything 'except the .playing div'. Is there any other way of achieving this?

Answer (score 3):

You've misunderstood the [.not method](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

> Given a jQuery object that represents
>   a set of DOM elements, the `.not()`
>   method constructs a new jQuery object
>   from a subset of the matching
>   elements. The supplied selector is
>   tested against each element; the
>   elements that don't match the selector
>   will be included in the result.

This means your query `$('body').not('.playing')` selects *all* bodies that *don't belong to the class* `.playing`.

As to a lights-out effect, usually this is implemented by creating a 100% width, 100% height div that is layered above the rest of the content.

Comment: Thanks George, do you have some example code for creating the lights out effect? I don't mean to sound lazy, I'm just a jQuery newbie and it will take me a few hours to figure that out.

Comment: @Sparrohawx jQuery TOOLS's [Expose](http://flowplayer.org/tools/toolbox/expose.html) plug in. Seriously though, if you search "jquery lights out" on Google you will find a lot of solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Change this line

```
$('body').not(".playing").animate({opacity: 0, backgroundColor: 'black'}, 1000);
```

to this

```
$('body *').not(".playing").animate({opacity: 0, backgroundColor: 'black'}, 1000);
```

Comment: I've tried them using jsfiddle and it's working: http://jsfiddle.net/LSF9Z/. Maybe you can post the html as well to better understand your problem.

Comment: Hi jSang, I've updated jsfiddle so that it matches my code a bit more - http://jsfiddle.net/LSF9Z/1/ but it seems to be having trouble. Maybe because it's an object?

Answer (score 1):

Final code for anyone looking at this. Solution taken from http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/05/17/Use-jQuery-to-turn-off-the-lights-while-watching-videos.aspx

```
//=Jay. Create div before Showreel.
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.videopress').before("<div class='lightsout'><p>Once the video starts playing hover your mouse here to dim the lights.</p></div>");
    $('body').before("<div id='curtain'></div>");
});

//=Jay. Showreel Curtain down
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".lightsout").hover(function(){
        $(this).next().addClass('playing');
        $('#curtain').delay(500).fadeIn();
    }, function(){
        $(this).next().removeClass('playing');
        $('#curtain').fadeOut();
    });
});
```

and the CSS...

```
/*=Jay. IE6 doesn't support Fixed positioning which is needed for the curtain below.*/
.ltie7 .lightsout {
    display: none;
}

.lightsout:hover {
    cursor: none;
}

#curtain {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    left:0; 
    top:0; 
    width:100%; 
    height: 100%;
    z-index:1000;
    background: black;
}

.playing {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1001;
}
```